# Shopify: Cannot get rid of an element even after editing base CSS

Tags: css, shopify

I have a `<p>` element which I wish to remove by `display:none`. I am adding the following code in the main CSS file (`core.css`). This file is getting referenced on all pages as per the Network tab. Also, in Inspect Element I see the code for this particular element is coming from inline styling, which isn't part of any asset file on Shopify Code Editor, and cannot be edited as a result. What is the way out here?

**Code I am adding to `core.css`:**

```
p.hulk-powered-wrapper {
    display:none !important;
  }
```

**Page in question:** https://shop.rallyappliances.com/pages/contact

Upon further investigation, I found that the only CSS file that is able to edit this element (where adding the following code works) is an external stylesheet from the app developer's website. However, given as the HTML is finally on my website, doesn't it mean I should have a master CSS which overrides the external CSS? In the screenshot I have marked which CSS file being loaded is able to make this change.

[image: CSS files being loaded]

Comment: can't override if content is loaded inside iframe.

Answer (score 1):

I added identical code in the Chrome DevTools and it worked (i.e., *Shopify Forms Powered by HulkApps* disappeared).

Two questions:

1. Is this the only thing you have inside the `core.css`?
2. I'm not familiar with Shopify, but in Magento 2 sometimes CSS doesn't work because of the cache. Have you cleared the cache?

---

**UPDATE**

1. I see you have a lot of code inside the `core.css`. Everything else works? Is this `display: none;` the only thing that doesn't?
2. I see that `p.hulk-powered-wrapper{display:none !important}` is inside the `core.css` so the problem shouldn't be related with the cache.

Comment: Everything else is default Shopify code, so it works, yes, such as heading font sizes, etc. This line is the only line I have added manually, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Hm, what if you create a new CSS file? Don't forget to include it in your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that p tag is inside an iframe, so maybe try something like this (with jQuery):

```
$("#frame_ai7L9yHu4aWawvcQdO6NJw").contents().find(".hulk-powered-wrapper").hide();
```

Comment: Is this supposed to go in the core.js file?

Comment: It would need to go in a document ready block somewhere - so just call it somewhere once the page is loaded, or in a script block with 'defer' maybe. Just needs to be running after the element is on the page. Put it in the footer first maybe to see if it works